# how to get the top k similar items given item vectors in spark dataframe?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, user-defined-functions, cosine-similarity

I get spark dataframe like bellow, `result` is the id's vector:

```
+--------------------+--------------------+ 
| id                 |              result| 
+--------------------+--------------------+ 
|000ab862128e11eab...|[-0.46, 0.31, 0.2]  | 
|0026f306128e11eab...|[-0.46, 0.31, 0.2]  | 
|00313b10d11b11ea9...|[-0.25, 0.70, 0.36] | 
|00337629128e11eab...|[-0.46, 0.31, 0.51] | 
|005492e4128e11eab...|[0.55, 0.66, 0.85]  | 
+--------------------+--------------------+
```

How to get the top 5 most similar items efficiently? I have defined a `cosineSimility` function, which takes two vectors in "result" as parameters.

Comment: you can use word2vec similarity function

Comment: word2vec similarity function just find similarity between words, this would not solve problems, because every "id" is constist of many words.I want to find similarity between "id"s.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `withColumn` to call 'cosineSimility' function and store its result as new column. Then sort the dataframe based on this new column and take top(n) rows.

```
<dataframe>.
withColumn("rank", cosineSimility(col("result"))).
sort(col("rank").desc).
top(5)
```

Comment: cosineSimility function takes two vectors in "result"  column as parameters, the usage in your answer is not correct.

Comment: this is an example to call a function, sort. I thought that was your question. You need to pass all parameters needed.